# Hotplug fallback to static ip

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

I try to achieve a network configuration on my device, that it will always get an ip-address from dhcp if available on plug in of rj45. Most of the time the device will boot up without connection. In `/etc/network/interfaces` i put following:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I want to add a rule or behaviour, that when i connect this device to a network with no dhcp

```
(device <---> [USB LAN] pc)
```

that my device get a static ip address.

I tried to add Multiple IP addresses on one Interface to the `interfaces` right under the `allow-hotplug` entry:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 10.0.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

All i get is `10.0.0.2` as ip on my device. I've heard about `lease` in  `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` but i never used it before.

Could you please help me to get my head around this network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to jump through hoops to accomplish this. All you really need is [`zeroconf`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zeroconf&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) Available in the [Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

`zeroconf` provides APIPA:

> Short for Automatic Private IP Addressing, a feature of later Windows
>      operating systems. With APIPA, DHCP clients can automatically
>      self-configure an IP address and subnet mask when a DHCP server isn't
>      available. When a DHCP client boots up, it first looks for a DHCP
>      server in order to obtain an IP address and subnet mask. If the client
>      is unable to find the information, it uses APIPA to automatically
>      configure itself with an IP address from a range that has been
>      reserved especially for Microsoft. The IP address range is 169.254.0.1
>      through 169.254.255.254. The client also configures itself with a
>      default class B subnet mask of 255.255.0.0. A client uses the
>      self-configured IP address until a DHCP server becomes available.
>
> APIPA is meant for nonrouted small business environments, usually less
>      than 25 clients.

Source: Memory and https://lists.debian.org/debian-russian/2005/11/msg00064.html

For further details regarding `zeroconf` see http://www.zeroconf.org/

(RFC 3927) specifies how IP hosts can assign addresses in the absence of outside configuration information. That means assigning addresses without depending on information entered by a human user, and without depending on information obtained over the network from a special server, such as a DHCP server.

You may also find [this useful.](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/10/msg00410.html)

Comment: Is it possible to let apipa assign always the same ip address or is it random?

Comment: expanded answer.